# Menu image for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm working with custom post type. I want to use custom menu image for the post type.
I know **'menu_icon' => ''** should work but couldn't recognize how image path should be specified. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just got the solution, this should be
  
`'menu_icon' => '"' .WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/plugindirname/images/image.png'. '"',`

Comment: Don't use WP_PLUGIN_URL directly. Instead use the plugin_url() function (refer to my answer). This will make it compatible with WPMU as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to give the full path to the image. Something like this

```
'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/portfolio-icon.png'
```

**Edit**: If you want to include the image from the Plugin directory, then you can use the [plugin_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function. This will make it compatible with WPMU as well.

```
'menu_icon' => plugins_url('path/to/image',  __FILE__);
```

Comment: Actually I was writing a plugin for library management where I included custom post type as books. So the image needed to be included into plugin dir, for me.
Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it, if the image you want to add is located in your theme directory, would be:

```
'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/your_custom_icon.png',
```