# WordPress custom post type menu icon

Tags: wordpress

I am having a hard time to reference the image from uploads folder in my theme. How can I call that folder?

Here's what I tried so far:

```
   add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
   function create_post_type() {
   register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add Product' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Product' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Product' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Product' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Products' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Products found' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' =>  get_template_directory_uri() . '/uploads/2013/11/product.png',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' )
    )
);
   }
```

But the problem is, it's not showing in my dashboard. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169491/menu-image-for-custom-post-type

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya thanks, but I want to call the image from the uploads folder. not from the plugin folder

Comment: Where is your upload folder?

Comment: inside wp-content folder

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` Retrieve template directory URI for the current theme,not wp-content folder path

Comment: I'm using get_template_directory_uri() but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
<?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>
<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']; ?>
```

to get upload directory path in your word press installation , because `get_template_directory_uri()` Retrieve template directory URI for the current theme,not wp-content folder path

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/icon.png',
```